# Phonegap javascript alerts not working?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am very new to phonegap as well as javascript and I'm trying to make a simple Contact Adder application but for some reason nothing happens when I try to add a contact. No alerts even appear. By the way, I am using an android emulator within eclipse to test my application. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Add Contacts</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        </head>
    <script>

    document.addEventListener("deviceready",deviceIsReady, false);

     function deviceIsReady()
     {
    document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click",addContact, false);
    alert("READY!");
      }
   function addContact()
    {
    var fullName = document.getElementById("first").value+ " " + document.getElementById("last").value;
    var theContact = navigator.contacts.create({"displayName" : fullName});
    theContact.save();
        alert("ADDED!");
     }
</script>           

   <body onload = "deviceIsReady()">
   <h1>Hello World</h1>

   <form>
    <label for="first">First</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="first"/><br>
    <label for="last">Last</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="last"/><br>
    <input type="button" value="Save Contact" id ="save"/>
    </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code working for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet"  href="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
          var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
        </script>
        <script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <title>Add Contacts</title>
        <script>
            function loaded(){
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceIsReady, false);
            }

            function deviceIsReady()
            {
                document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", addContact, false);
                alert("READY!");
            }
            function addContact()
            {
                var fullName = document.getElementById("first").value+ " " + document.getElementById("last").value;
                var theContact = navigator.contacts.create({"displayName" : fullName});
                theContact.save();
                alert("ADDED!");
            }
        </script>  
    </head>         

   <body onload = "loaded()">
   <h1>Hello World</h1>

   <form>
    <label for="first">First</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="first"/><br>
    <label for="last">Last</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="last"/><br>
    <input type="button" value="Save Contact" id ="save"/>
    </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

I tried in eclipse with android sdk, and I get the alerts on the emulator and after I add a new contact I sow it on the contacts. Before you try this code watch out for the script and style link. (rewrite it, or download the newest)

[image: http://imageshack.us/a/img841/7938/b5x4.jpg]

[image: http://imageshack.us/a/img28/6060/9xfr.jpg]

[image: http://imageshack.us/a/img835/6729/yl8e.jpg]

Answer (score -1):

Your `script` tag is in-between the `head` and `body` tags.  Try moving it into the body tag.

Your window load event also probably won't work.  Just remove it, and simply attach the device ready event, so your script looks like this:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("deviceready",deviceIsReady, false);

function deviceIsReady() {
    document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click",addContact, false);
    alert("READY!");
}

function addContact() {
    var fullName = document.getElementById("first").value+ " " + document.getElementById("last").value;
    var theContact = navigator.contacts.create({"displayName" : fullName});
    theContact.save();
    alert("ADDED!");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Added some more to my answer

Comment: Please note I don't have phonegap set up to test the actual contact stuff, but hopefully this gets the `deviceready` event functioning properly for you.

Comment: ok, now the ready alert is shown whenever the application opens, but when I click submit to add the contact, nothing happens. Looks like the addContact() method is never being entered?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally pasted in the top line with "click" instead of "deviceready" (I used click as I was testing in a browser) so you might've copied it over before I fixed it up.  Change it back to device ready.

Comment: If you move the alert to the top of the addContact function, you will be able to see if the function is being fired (because the function may have an error before the alert gets called as it is currently written)

Comment: ok I just did that, now there are no alerts again, not even ready. Ok, I will try to move to the top of the function and see what happens

Comment: The big issues is probably this... You haven't included the PhoneGap javascript file!!

Comment: Moving to the top did nothing. I don't think that is the problem because the javascript that I included should work. But just incase, I just tried the phonegap javascript file and it causes the same issue.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the deviceready is not being called? Because I am not getting the ready alert.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30521/discussion-between-sklak-and-appclay)

Comment: I got the ready to work, look at updated code. Submit contact button is still not working though

Comment: The error is definitely in this line.. some sort of syntax error:
 var theContact = navigator.contacts.create({"displayName": fullName});

Answer (score -2):

just remove the

```
 <body onload = "deviceIsReady()">
```

and make a simple

```
<body>
```

you also need to put your

```
<script>
```

in head or body, but not between them!

you need to catch the event ondevice ready, but not on bodylaod. so try this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        document.addEventListener("deviceready",deviceIsReady, false);

        function deviceIsReady(){
           alert("READY!");
        }
        </script> 
   </head>
   <body>
   <h1>Hello World</h1>

   <form>
    <label for="first">First</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="first"/><br>
    <label for="last">Last</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="last"/><br>
    <input type="button" value="Save Contact" id ="save"/>
    </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

it should works (for me, it works!). if not, check the manifest, maybe you do something wrong with it

Comment: I'ld be surprised if **this works for you**, as you're not loading *phonegap.js* at all. As a result, your "deviceready" is never being caught by any phonegap api... so it won't do anything (except producing a javascript error). ;)

Comment: You *might* want to edit your answer then (and correct that "bodylaod" typo while you're at it). ;)